# How to refresh page when element isn't displayed

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to refresh the page when an element I am trying to find isnt displayed I have written this code but instead of just skipping the if statement the test just fails

```
while (true)
{
    if (Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.LinkText("Leather Utility Vest")).Displayed)
    {
        var clickButton = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.LinkText("Leather Utility Vest"));
        clickButton.Click();
        break;
    }
    Driver.Instance.Navigate().Refresh();
}
```

Comment: I imagine "just fails" may mean "never terminates". If something else happens (eg. an exception was thrown?), be sure to explain what - *with an appropriate level of useful detail.*

Comment: @user2864740 The test fails because the element wasnt found

Answer (score 1):

I just used this code instead

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        var clickButton = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.LinkText("Leather Utility Vest"));
        clickButton.Click();
        break;
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        Driver.Instance.Navigate().Refresh();
    }
}
```

This catches the error that the element wasn't found which was why the test was failing and runs the catch block which refreshes the webpage